# What's the proper way to punctuate inches when recording the dimensions of something?

Tags: punctuation

When punctuating the dimensions of something, if both dimensions share the same units, does the punctuation occur after each measurement or just after the last one. For example, if I'm looking at a sheet of paper, which is correct: {8 1/2 x 11"} or is {8 1/2" x 11"}?

Comment: This question is not specific to any language, and the expertise needed is more engineering, not linguistics or related fields. It is not a good fit for [english.se].

Comment: I reserve judgement as to whether this is Off Topic or not. In speech some people would say *"Eight and a half by eleven inches"*, but many (possibly *most*) would say *"Eight and a half inches by eleven inches"*. In written form, if you're using **"** as a symbol for **inches**, that would ***always*** be repeated wherever relevant.

Comment: Where a symbol is used, repeat for **each** and every instance, where the word is used, mention **once** at the end. 8 1/2" x 11"; 8 1/2 x 11 inch.

Comment: Two recommendations regarding a question that is clearly off-topic as either a matter of opinion, or one that can only be answered in relation to the style of specific technical areas. 1. Use the metric system and decimals. 2. Use the ‘times’ character rather than the letter ‘x’.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would say the opposite, literally (as in, "8 and a half by 11 inches"), and WRT your assertion that "possibly most" would say it like you do. Ib fact, where anecdotal experience is concerned, I believe I hear simply "8 and a half by 11"—no unit at all—with much greater frequency. This is esp. true when it is used as a noun, i.e., "Are there any 8 ½ ⨉ 11s left?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the punctuation after each number. Otherwise you may get confusion on the first number - not just about feet vs. inches, but also because it's common notation to write

> (number) x (thing)

to indicate quantity and it may be read as "8 of the 11 inch widgets".

Also this may be personal preference but decimal is much easier to read than fraction for measurements, e.g. *8.5" x 11"* instead of *8½" x 11"*

Comment: I find fractions much easier to read.  Definitely prefer them.

Comment: For measures of ½, it is indeed easy to read as decimal, but a fraction like ⅐ is horrific to read as decimal: 0.142857... The dificulty or reading ½ is overwelmingly smaller than reading the decimal version of ⅐, and so is it the case for most fractions.

Answer (score 1):

8.5" x 11" seems to be the cleanest way to write these numbers in a text.

Other proper ways are 8 1/2" x 11", 8.5in x 11in, 8.5 x 11 Inches.

However, 8" 1/2, 8"1/2, 8in 1/2 are not proper. The inch symbol " (or in) comes at the end only.

Each writing goes with personal preferences, but consistency is key.
As Samuel Charpentier noted in his comment from Nov 2020, 8 1/2" can be a better choice for those who are more used to fractional system. 8 1/7" is much cleaner than 8.142857...", so if you have to use rarer fractions, be consistent and use fractions.

If you are giving someone else measurements from your tape measurement, you might as well use fractions as they are often featured on many tape measurements. 4 1/16" is easier than 4.0625".

My own experience with this started in 1995 when I moved from France to NY. I ordered a piece of glass to be cut at 24" x 38.75". When I came back to pick up the order, it was not ready, because the guy did not understand 38.75".
I had to rewrite my measurements in fractions 24" x 38 3/4". It was (and still is) so unnatural to me...

Answer (score 0):

You should use the punctuation after each measurement, even if they are the same unit of measure, for the following reasons:

1. 8.5 X 11" looks almost like a quotation without an opening quotation mark.
2. The statement indicates the relationship between two measurements. Using the punctuation with both numbers ensures that it will be interpreted that way not as just a multiplication problem.
3. Consistent use of the punctuation with each measurement prevents misunderstandings or uncertainties about the units of measure in use.